# fast smooth scroll on mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I have a project in which I want fast smooth scrolling. I tried lot and I find some solutions. But they all can't scroll smooth when I rotate mouse wheel multiple times at a time and the last rotate of mouse wheel get smooth. After tons of searching I got a example of what i want. But I can't figure out what's is the js function. [Here is the example](http://demo1.artillegence.com/wakana/). I don't want to use any plugin because I already used too many plugins in my project and for this it's loads so slow. Is it possible with only Jquery or pure javascript?

Answer (score 1):

It's not my solution but I thought it's fitting and pretty neat so I will just copy-paste it:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing, {
  easeOutQuint: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t * t * t + 1) + b;
  }
});

var wheel = false,
  $docH = $(document).height() - $(window).height(),
  $scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  if (wheel === false) {
    $scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  }
});
$(document).bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e, delta) {
  delta = delta || -e.originalEvent.detail / 3 || 
  e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 5; //edit this to your needs - the higher the slower
  wheel = true;

  $scrollTop = Math.min($docH, Math.max(0, parseInt($scrollTop - delta * 30)));
  $($.browser.webkit ? 'body' : 'html').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $scrollTop + 'px'
  }, 2000, 'easeOutQuint', function() {
    wheel = false;
  });
  return false;
});
```

This overwrites the default behaviour for scroll events.
Source and full credits to Fiddle User [Szar](https://jsfiddle.net/user/Szar/fiddles/) - fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Szar/xmkwa8ft/

P.S. this was found in a 1min google search using the term "smooth mouse scroll css"